# Can't seem to allocate vector properly

Tags: c++

I am attempting to write a program that takes hex string input and converts it to binary.  For the life of me, I can't seem to write this properly.  The main culprit so far is that I can't initialize the output vector in the hex_decode function properly.  See the gdb output.  I don't normally use c++ stl and string streams for this kind of thing but I thought I'd try something new.  This is biting me in the butt and looks too simple, but its clearly wrong.  What am I missing?

code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

std::vector<uint8_t> hex_decode(std::string input){
  std::vector<uint8_t> output;

  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i+=2) {
    output.push_back(0);
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i+=2) {
    uint8_t n = 0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << input[i];
    ss >> std::hex >> n;
    n = n <<4;
    output[i/2] += n;
    ss >> std::hex >> n;
    output[i/2] += n;
  }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::string input;
  std::vector<uint8_t> decode;
  std::cin >> input;

  decode = hex_decode(input);
  for (auto&& b : decode) {
    std::cout << b;
  }
}
```

gdb output

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004015e1 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdc48) at mapConverterMain.cc:37
(gdb) info locals
b = <error reading variable>
__for_range = @0x7fffffffdac0: {<std::_Vector_base<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >> = {
    _M_impl = {<std::allocator<unsigned char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<unsigned char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>, 
      _M_finish = 0x7fffffffdb10 "\300\003", 
      _M_end_of_storage = 0x603d88 "@\022@"}}, <No data fields>}
__for_begin = {_M_current = 0x1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>}
__for_end = {_M_current = 0x7fffffffdb10 "\300\003"}
input = {static npos = 18446744073709551615, 
  _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
    _M_p = 0x618030 "0012811738003000213106014c4d941e229016220f7e02dc0e2002240000000388a40654a626c890013ece229031bb989b0df2050512011200000000622901a28989b24d062290329f989b108249058000448190002241d00010400cc80000000311480d"...}, _M_string_length = 566, {
    _M_local_buf = "\300\003\000\000\000\000\000\000\063\070\060\060\063\060\060", 
    _M_allocated_capacity = 960}}
decode = {<std::_Vector_base<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >> = {
    _M_impl = {<std::allocator<unsigned char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<unsigned char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>, 
      _M_finish = 0x7fffffffdb10 "\300\003", 
      _M_end_of_storage = 0x603d88 "@\022@"}}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004015e1 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdc48) at mapConverterMain.cc:37
(gdb) print decode.size()
$3 = 140737488345871
(gdb) print input.length()
$4 = 566
(gdb)
```

input data file

```
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
```

Comment: Please don't add working code to the question itself, as it may confuse future readers. Post it as an answer instead. Also there's no need to add "SOLVED" to the question body, accepting an answer is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by reaching at the end of non-void function `hex_decode` without executing `return` statement.

add

```
  return output;
```

before the

```
}
```

that represents the end of function body of the function `hex_decode`.

Comment: Ugh.  not even a warning from g++

Comment: @Joshua Use `-Wall -Wextra` option, and g++ will warn about that. https://wandbox.org/permlink/LxdhG1C1BwidWjEa

Comment: That solved my problem.  My code is still wrong right now but I'll mark this as solved.

Comment: The issue with my code is that ss << input[i]; ss >> std::hex >> n somewhere converts the numeric into a char.

Comment: use of uint8_t for n results in downgrading (is that the right word?) the value to a char, which messes up the string stream handling such that the char code is returned from the stream, not the integer value

Answer (score 0):

Working code is below. I tried several different approaches, and there is likely a better way to preallocated the output array, but I've spent too much time on sillier bugs and this is a small util that runs once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

std::vector<uint8_t> hex_decode(std::string input){
  std::vector<uint8_t> output;

  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i+=2) {
    output.push_back(0);
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i+=2) {
    int n = 0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << input[i] << input[i+1];
    std::cerr << "Input is " << input[i];;
    ss >> std::hex >> n;
    std::cerr << " n is "  << std::hex << n <<std::endl;
    output[i/2] = n;
  }
  return output;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::string input;
  std::vector<uint8_t> decode;
  std::cin >> input;

  MessageFrame_t messageFrame = 0;
  asn_dec_rval_t rval;
  

  decode = hex_decode(input);
  for (auto&& b : decode) {
    std::cout << b;
  }
}
```